# Meaning of 誰もいはしない in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-は, renyōkei

> 「どうせ誰も**いはしない**と高をくくっていたところもある。」

This one's throwing me for a bit of a loop. The translation says "He also didn't really take the possibility of anyone being there seriously."

It makes sense to me except for the いはしない part. What does this mean?

I looked up い and saw that it can mean stomach, so my first thought was that いはしない was perhaps some idiom like "not doing his stomach" that means "not being there" but I can't find any evidence to justify that on the internet so I have to assume it's wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The sentence is ***not*** about someone's stomach.  If it were, 「い」 would have certainly been written in kanji as 「胃{い}」.  Besides, 「胃はしない」 makes no sense to begin with.

> 「Verb in 連用形{れんようけい} (continuative form) + は + しない」
>
> = "would not (verb) one bit" ← rather emphatic

「い」 is the 連用形 of the verb 「いる」 ("to be", "to exist").

> 「誰{だれ}も**い**はしない」, therefore, means "***no one would be (there)***"

You will encounter this grammar pattern over and over.  That I can guarantee.

Note that the 「は」 is occasionally replaced by a 「や」 in more informal speech.

I have noticed over the years that when the single-syllable 連用形 of some of the two-syllable verbs (two in dictionary forms) is used in phrases and sentences, quite a few Japanese-learners do not seem to even notice that they are seeing/hearing a verb there.  Verbs are too important to just not notice in any language.  Those verbs include:

「い」 for 「いる」

「し」 for 「する」

「き」 for 「来{く}る」 and 「着{き}る」

「み」 for 「見る」, etc.

「し」 is the one most often used and this website is indeed full of questions regarding phrases containing it.

Comment: Thanks, are you aware of anywhere I can read more about this? I'm searching for "stem + はする" and such but unfortunately not turning up much.

Comment: @user21871 We have some previous questions that touch on this topic, which I just retagged: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reny%C5%8Dkei+particle-wa