# Which of these sentences are correct?

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjugations, form

1 読みはしない

2 読みもしない

3 読みをしない

4 お読みしない

5 読みしない

6 読むことをしない

7 読むことなんてしない

I used the verb 読む for no particular reason. Can someone confirm which of these sentences have correct grammar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **読みはしない**: Correct. This is how you can [add a contrastive-wa to a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25727/5010).

   > 買いはするが、読みはしない。
   > I'll *buy* it, but won't *read* it.
2. **読みもしない**: Correct. "don't *even* read".

   > 彼は本を買っても読みもしない。
   > He buys books, but doesn't even read them.
3. **読みをしない**: Correct only if 読み is clearly treated as a noun meaning "reading (of a kanji, etc.)".

   > AとBは同じ読みをしない。
   > A and B don't have the same reading.
4. **お読みしない**: Correct (but uncommon). This is the negative version of お読みする, which a humble version of 読む.

   > お読みしないわけにはいきません。
   > I cannot afford not to read it.
5. **読みしない**: Correct but rare. This is valid only in a colloquial sentence where 読み is clearly treated as a noun and を has been omitted.

   > 同じ読みしない漢字10個書いて。
   > Write 10 kanji that don't read the same.
6. **読むことをしない**: Correct ("not to do the reading").

   > 彼は本を買っても読むことをしない。
   > He buys books but never reads them.
7. **読むことなんてしない**: Correct ("not to do something (nonsense/etc) like reading").

   > 説明書を全部読むことなんてしないよ。
   > I won't bother reading the entire manual.

Note that 3 and 5 can appear only in uncommon situations where 読み is working as a [masu-stem as a noun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010). They are incorrect as verb forms in general.